# SQL Server Stored Procedure Execution stuck runnable

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, database-administration

I have a stored procedure that has two transactions. The first is to delete rows from a table based on an inner join to a control table. The second is to insert rows back into the same table using another inner join on the same control table.

The performance of this stored procedure is variable. Sometimes I can execute it to insert a few thousand rows (<15,000) in a couple of seconds. The very next time I try to execute it moves straight to runnable with the last wait being SOS_Scheduler_Yield. I've been searching this wait and somewhat understand.

I've checked things like:

- the power settings on the server (max frequency on CPU). The CPU is not busy before I try to execute - it is typically at less than 1% and jumps to 13% while the execution is 'hung'.
- Decreasing the number of results it needs to process down to a few hundred and sometimes works quickly - but sometimes hangs the same way
- I've tried recompiling the query plan with no improvement
- Rebuilt the indexes on the 2 involved tables with no improvement (clustered index)
- Checked the query plan. The most expensive operation is the clustered index insert. I don't think that this is the issue though, because sometimes it executes fine.

I'm on SQL Server 2012 within a VM.

Things to try?

Table creation:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [A].[SummLoads](
    [shiftID_L] [int] NULL,
    [Excav] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    --50 more columns here
    [ExcelDate] [int] NULL,
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_SummLoads] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [B].[sp_SSISsumLoads]

AS
BEGIN
--EXEC sp_recompile 'MDM.[B].[sp_SSISsumLoads]'  Force Recompile
--BEGIN TRAN
--Delete shifts to be replaced
DELETE sl 
FROM mdm.a.summLoads sl 
INNER JOIN mdm.tmp.ALD_Control AC 
    ON sl.shiftID_L = MDM.A.fn_SI_to_ShiftID(l_shiftindex) 

--Re-insert removed data
INSERT INTO MDM.A.SummLoads 
SELECT 
     [shiftID_L]
    ,[Excav]
    ,[OperEx]
    --some columns omitted
    ,sum([GrOx]*ALD.TonnesLoaded) AS 'GrOx'
    ,datediff(d,'1899-12-30',MDM.A.fn_shiftID_to_date([shiftID_l]))

  FROM [MDM].[A].[ALDsun] ALD
  INNER JOIN MDM.B.Materials GM
    ON ALD.MatCode# = GM.MatCode#
INNER JOIN mdm.tmp.ALD_Control AC 
        ON ShiftID_L = MDM.A.fn_SI_to_ShiftID(AC.l_shiftindex) 

LEFT OUTER JOIN mdm.b.eGOH_Factors AS EF 
    ON  EF.eqmtModel# = ALD.EqmtModelTk#


GROUP BY
[shiftID_L]

  ,[Excav]
  ,[OperEx]
   ,EqmtModelEx
  ,EqmtModelEx#
    ,EqmtModelTk
  ,[EqmtModelTk#]
   ,[Mine]
  ,[Mine#]
   ,contractor
,contractor#
  ,GM.MatCode
  ,GM.MatCode#
  ,GM.MatType
  ,GM.MatDPR
  ,GM.Prod
  ,GM.Prod#
  ,[GradeID]
  ,[LocDig]
  ,[LocDump]
   ,[DumpArea];
```

Note: joined tables in sp are small helpers (<50 rows) with clustered indexes.

Edit 2: I checked VM resource allocation. CPU is not under sustained pressure and never goes over 25%. Memory is as 62Gb out of 65Gb, but performance monitor within the VM has essentially all of this being held by the SQL server service.

Comment: Though your question is well-worded, it doesn't eliminate the possibility that your SQL might have one thing out of place.  Can you afford to post the procedure and table creation scripts?

Comment: Do you have insight into the hosts utilization underlying your VM?  Could it be near capacity or set to dynamically migrate the guest?

Comment: Are you certain there is no memory "over commitment" in the VM pool? This was a typical issue in the past where basically the VM reports it has memory but behind the scenes (in the VM tools) it actually doesn't. I think it's called ballooning.